# minikube - EXTERNAL-IP remains <pending>

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

My Service definition is as follows

```
# SOURCE: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: guestbook
    tier: frontend
spec:
  # if your cluster supports it, uncomment the following to automatically create
  # an external load-balanced IP for the frontend service.
  # type: LoadBalancer
  type: LoadBalancer
  #type: NodePort
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - targetPort: 80
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: guestbook
    tier: frontend
```

After applying it

[image]

I was expecting to get External IP as explained [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/#viewing-the-frontend-service-via-loadbalancer) but instead, it remains pending and doesn't change as shown below
[image]
Can you please help me find why I'm not getting EXTERNAL-IP?

Comment: The **EXTERNAL-IP** column might show **<pending>** while the **load balancer** is being created. It can take a few minutes for the Load Balancer to be created. Can you run the **kubectl get** command now and check.

Comment: This is the problem that it remains like this forever.

Comment: Services of type LoadBalancer can be exposed via the minikube tunnel command. It must be run in a separate terminal window to keep the LoadBalancer running. For more info refer to the [link](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel)

Comment: Have you tried **minikube tunnel**?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should try **[minikube tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel)**. After starting the minikube, you have to execute this command -

```
$ minikube tunnel
```

> *minikube tunnel* runs as a process, creating a network route on the host to the service CIDR of the cluster using the cluster’s IP address as a gateway.

Answer (score 0):

where are you running this minikube, if you are running it on your local, external ip will not appear, as external-ip is specific to external cloud providers.